# prevent rgl from opening window in package examples

Tags: r, package, rgl

I have several packages that make extensive use of rgl in documentation examples.  Every time I do `R CMD check`, every such example opens a collection of rgl windows briefly, which is annoying.

Is there some rgl setting I can use in the `.Rd` files to suppress this behavior? Is there any downside to doing this?

Comment: I think if you unset `DISPLAY` then `rgl` will be silent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the environment variable `RGL_USE_NULL=TRUE` and `rgl` won't try to open any windows.

This should be done outside of R, before running `R CMD check`.  It can also be done inside R using `Sys.setenv(RGL_USE_NULL = TRUE)` before loading `rgl` if you don't want to see `rgl` displays during an interactive session.

Comment: Ah, I thought I had seen something like this before.  But:  I don't know how to set this in a package for the purpose of running `R CMD`s to check, build, etc.  I certainly can't put this into `.Rd` files.

Comment: You shouldn't.  This is something for the person running the checks to set.  Do it before running them.